# Update keyboard prediction bar suggestions swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a sign up screen which has 4 textfields, First name, last name, email & password.

Apple keyboard prediction for password works fine but for others

First Name textfield shows "Full Name" in prediction
Last Name shows "Full Name"
email textfield shows "Password" key on right.

How can i update this to show
First Name textfield's prediction will show "FirstName" instead of "FirstName lastName"
same with last Name textfield
and for email textfield it should show "emailaddress@,," in prediction

this is not a custom keyboard 
UILexicon doesn't work

Comment: Have you set the `textContentType` of your text field?

Answer (score 3):

You should set the `textContentType` property of your fields to the appropriate value in order to let iOS know the suggestions it should provide:

e.g.

```
 myGivenNameField.textContentType = UITextContentType.givenName
 mySurnameField.textContentType = UITextContentType.familyName
```